# Getting preceding and following datetime from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below showing time, subject and on_time.

```
    created_time       subject          on_time
2020-02-26 21:01:40      A        2020-02-26 21:08:40
2020-02-26 21:01:40      A        2020-02-26 21:01:43
2020-02-26 21:01:40      A        2020-02-26 20:50:55
2020-02-26 21:01:40      A        2020-02-26 21:44:40
2020-02-26 01:01:50      B        2020-02-26 01:01:52
2020-02-26 01:01:50      B        2020-02-26 00:08:40
2020-02-26 01:01:50      B        2020-02-26 01:08:40
2020-02-26 01:01:50      B        2020-02-26 00:59:15
```

I need output dataframe showcasing the created_time, subject and on_time just preceding and just following the created_time like

```
    created_time       subject     on_time_preceding     on_time_following
2020-02-26 21:01:40      A        2020-02-26 21:44:40   2020-02-26 21:01:43
2020-02-26 01:01:50      B        2020-02-26 00:59:15   2020-02-26 01:01:52
```

on_time_preceding is the nearest preceding on_time just before the created_time and on_time_following is the nearest following on_time just after the created_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works

```
import pandas as pd
import io

table = """
created_time|subject|on_time
2020-02-26 21:01:40|A|2020-02-26 21:08:40
2020-02-26 21:01:40|A|2020-02-26 21:01:43
2020-02-26 21:01:40|A|2020-02-26 20:50:55
2020-02-26 21:01:40|A|2020-02-26 21:44:40
2020-02-26 01:01:50|B|2020-02-26 01:01:52
2020-02-26 01:01:50|B|2020-02-26 00:08:40
2020-02-26 01:01:50|B|2020-02-26 01:08:40
2020-02-26 01:01:50|B|2020-02-26 00:59:15
"""
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(table), parse_dates=['created_time', 'on_time'], sep='|')
print(df[df['created_time'] > df['on_time']]
      .sort_values('on_time')
      .drop_duplicates(['created_time', 'subject'], keep='last')
      .merge(df[df['created_time'] < df['on_time']].groupby('subject')['on_time'].min(),
             left_on='subject', right_index=True, suffixes=('_preceding', '_following'))
      .sort_values('subject')
      .reset_index(drop=True))

# output:     
         created_time subject   on_time_preceding   on_time_following
0 2020-02-26 21:01:40       A 2020-02-26 20:50:55 2020-02-26 21:01:43
1 2020-02-26 01:01:50       B 2020-02-26 00:59:15 2020-02-26 01:01:52
```